# Complex analysis: Rewrite $\cos^{-1}{i}$ in algebraic form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm stuck in this problem (complex analysis), my answer is not the one reported in the book:

> *Rewrite $\cos^{-1}{i}$ in the algebraic form.* **A: $k\pi + i \frac{\ln{2}}{2}\ \forall\ k \in \mathbb{Z}$**

So I tried this approach in order to solve it:

- As $\cos^{-1}{z} = -i \ln{\left( z \pm \sqrt{z^2 - 1} \right)}$, doing $z = i$ and $i^2 = -1$ where necessary, we have

$$\cos^{-1}{i} = -i \ln{\left( i \pm \sqrt{i^2 - 1} \right)} = -i \ln{\left( i \pm \sqrt{-2} \right)} = -i \ln{\left( i \pm i \sqrt{2} \right)}$$

- Factoring $i$ and separating the obtained logarithm of product into sum of logarithms:

$$\cos^{-1}{i} = -i \ln{\left[ i \left( 1 \pm \sqrt{2} \right) \right]} = -i \big[ \ln{i} + \ln{\left( 1 \pm \sqrt{2} \right)} \big]$$

- Solving $\ln{i}$ separately, we obtain $\ln{i} = \pi i \left( 2k + \frac{1}{2} \right)$
- Solving $\ln{\left( 1 \pm \sqrt{2} \right)}$, on the other hand, yields

$$\ln{\left( 1 \pm \sqrt{2} \right)} = \begin{cases} \ln{\left( \sqrt{2} + 1 \right)} + \pi i \cdot 2k & (+) \\ \ln{\left( \sqrt{2} - 1 \right)} + \pi i \left( 2k + 1 \right) & (-) \end{cases}$$

- Substituting these expressions into the original one, we have

$$\cos^{-1}{i} = \begin{cases} \pi \left( 4k + \frac{1}{2} \right) -i \ln{\left( \sqrt{2} + 1 \right)} & (+) \\ \pi \left( 4k + \frac{3}{2} \right) -i \ln{\left( \sqrt{2} - 1 \right)} & (-) \end{cases}$$

which obviously doesn't correspond with the book. Is something wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The book is wrong. But you also made a small mistake. The $k$ coming from $\ln i$ does not have to be the same $k$ as the one in  $\ln(1\pm\sqrt2)$. Remember that the complex cosine also has period $2\pi$, so the answers should have that $k\cdot2\pi$ ambiguity - not $4\pi$ as you have. The other comment I want to make is not about a mistake but rather a check: the compex cosine is still even, so the two families of answers should be negatives of each other. Here $(\sqrt2+1)(\sqrt2-1)=1$ so their logarithms are negatives of each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me obtain an answer similar to yours by different means. Rather than use the algebraic form of the inverse cosine, I'll invert to solve for $x=e^{iz}$ and then invert again to get $z$. Carrying this out gives

\begin{align}
z=\cos^{-1} i
&\underset{\text{invert}}{\implies} i=\cos z=\frac{1}{2}(x+x^{-1})\implies x^2-2i x+1=0\\
&\underset{\text{solve}}{\implies} x=\dfrac{1}{2}\left(2i\pm \sqrt{-8}\right)=\pm i(\sqrt{2}\pm 1)\\
&\underset{\text{invert}}{\implies} z=-i\log x=\pm \frac{\pi}{2}+2\pi n-i\log(\sqrt{2}\pm 1)
\end{align}

This does not appear to agree with the book either...

Comment: I have a question: @Jyrki (if I understood what he said) told me the (in this case) $n$'s would be different, because $\ln{i}$, $\ln{\left( \sqrt{2} + 1 \right)}$ and $\ln{\left( \sqrt{2} - 1 \right)}$ have their own $k$'s (they aren't the same), and preserve the $\cos(z)$ period of $2\pi$. Do you consider your $n$'s as if you could join them, or how do I know I can consider only one $n$?

Comment: I don't think the issue raised by @JyrkiLahtonen comes up in my answer, since I took the precaution of writing $x$ in the second line as the product of a pure phase $(\pm i)$ and a positive real number $(\sqrt{2}\pm 1)$. In your answer, by comparison, you directly took the log of $1\pm \sqrt{2}$ (which is negative for the lower root). So b/c of that you've got two ambiguities to worry about.

Answer (score 0):

The answer in the book is wrong.